# Populate the URL params in title

Tags: php, javascript

I need help in populating the parameter in the url in the title of the page. What's the best way to do this?

www.mydns.com/sometext1/sometext2

sometext1 | sometext2

Thank you

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 4):

You want to update the page's title based on the url?

```
document.title = window.location.pathname.split("/").slice(1).join(" | ");
```

1. [window.location.pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) gives you {{/sometext1/sometext2}}
2. split will divide it up
3. slice(1) will chop off the empty index
4. join will put it back together

Comment: Doing this in JS means it's broken for people without JS and horrible for SEO.

Answer (score 3):

Of if you wanted to achieve this in PHP

```
<title>My Page<?php echo str_replace('/',' | ',substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1)); ?></title>
```